# Which DBCC commands do I need to run to make sure SQL Server's caches are totally clean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dbcc

I want to do some SQL Server performance testing and I want to establish a good baseline. I want to flush all the caches each time so that I know between each test it hasn't cached something so it performs better in between runs. Which DBCC commands should I use to make my SQL server as clean as possible?

Comment: This is better suited to ServerFault.com

Comment: @Raj More: nah, it's performance tuning/testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) and [`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)

This applies from at least SQL Server 2000

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you. I just couldn't remember them.